# Making a faster alternative for {PatternSequence[1, PatternSequence[2, 3 ..] ..] ..}

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching

I need to improve a pattern or switch an approach.

It is best described by an example

For a hierarchy/order given by a list e.g.:

```
order = {1, 2, 3}
```

and a list:

```
list = {
  1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3,
   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
  }
```

I need to verify that `list` matches a sequence defined by `order`:

```
MatchQ[list, {PatternSequence[1, PatternSequence[2, 3 ..] ..] ..}]
```

This pattern scales very poorly, already that one won't finish evaluating.

The function should only take `list` as an argument, consider the order constant. The pattern does not need to be constructed automatically.

Comment: Nesting `Repeated` can lead to immense back-tracking in the evaluation. I assume that is what's happening in this example. Maybe a finite state machine approach would work better?

Answer (score 10):

The following seems to work for me, unless I am missing something:

```
ClearAll[match]
match[{}][{}] := True;
match[{fst_, rest___}][l_List] :=
  And @@ Map[
    Replace[
      match[{rest}][#], 
      False :> Return[False, Map]
    ]&,
    Replace[
      ReplaceList[
        l, 
        {
          {___, fst, middle : Except[fst] ..., fst, ___} :> {middle}, 
          {___, fst, r : Except[fst] ...} :> {r}
        }
      ],
      {} -> False
    ]
 ]
```

(The part `Replace[match[{rest}][#], False :> Return[False, Map]]&` is optional and can in principle be replaced with just `match[{rest}]`).

Example:

```
match[{1, 2, 3}][list] // AbsoluteTiming
match[{1, 2, 3}][Append[list, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.00038, True} *)

(* {0.000383, False} *)
```

Comment: Incidentally, this is my answer #666.

Comment: The devil you say.

Answer (score 10):

This solution tries to reduce the list into a list of a single type of elements, if it succeeds then the list is following the prescribed pattern.

```
MatchQ[
  SequenceReplace[
   SequenceReplace[list, {2, 3 ..} :> x],
   {1, x ..} :> y
   ],
  {y ..}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.0019598, True}`

This is a take on the state machine that Daniel recommended in a comment:

```
f[1, 2] = 2;
f[2, 3] = 3;
f[3, 2] = 2;
f[3, 1] = 1;
f[3, 3] = 3;
f[_, _] := Throw[False]

And[
  First[list] == 1 && Last[list] == 3,
  Catch[Fold[f, list]; True]
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.0000455, True}`

Comment: I meanwhile implemented state-machine by mapping and working with current/last value, yours is much simpler and idiomatic.

Comment: Though, will it work for {2,3} or {1,2,3,1}, to not match? Can't test right now.

Comment: @Kuba You are right, I made an updated check that the sequence starts with a 1 and ends in a 3.